# opensuse samba client connect to windows server

Tags: linux, client, samba, opensuse

A opensuse 13.1 with samba client installed (which was in the OS installation disk). The machine has IP address but does not have DNS name registered. But when using "smbclient  //myserver/myshare -A smbpw" then I got Error NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL.

In order to access Windows Server, do I have to configure samba client? if so, what steps do I have to do? I am new to samba and system admin of linux, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to specify the domain/workgroup:

```
smbclient -W mydomain -U myusername //myserver/myshare
```

It seems that the domain entry in the samba authfile is ignored.

What works for me is:

```
$ cat authfile
username=mydomain\myuser
password=mysecrete
$ chmod 600 authfile
$ smbclient -A authfile //myserver/myshare
Domain=[mydomain] OS=[myos] Server=[myproduct]
smb: \>
```

What also works:

```
$ cat authfile
username=myuser
password=mysecrete
$ chmod 600 authfile
$ smbclient -W mydomain -A authfile //myserver/myshare
Domain=[mydomain] OS=[myos] Server=[myproduct]
smb: \>
```

Does not work:

```
$ cat authfile
username=myuser
password=mysecrete
domain=mydomain
$ chmod 600 authfile
$ smbclient -A authfile //myserver/myshare
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
smb: \>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Is the domain for Windows? how about the user name (windows logon or linux)? I put the user credentials in smbpw file with formats like: username=myusername password=mypassword domain=mydomain

Comment: yes the domain is the windows domain/workgroup. i've edited my answer.